# Recuperar datos de backend en ComponentDidMount o en ComponentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente componente:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import data from '../data/dummyDataEx.json'

export default class Resumen extends Component {

  constructor (...args) {
    super(...args)
    this.state = {
      results: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ results: data })
  }

  render() {
    const { datos } = this.state.results
    return (
      <div>
        <br/>
        <p>Título: {datos.titulo}</p>
        <p>Actualización: {datos.actualizacion}</p>
        <p>Estado: {datos.estado}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

y el dummyDataEx.json

```
{
  "datos": {
    "titulo": "Esto es el título",
    "actualizacion": "22/10/2016 19:10:42",
    "estado": "Cerrado"
  }
}
```

La ejecución de este componente da error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'titulo' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando `componentDidMount`, pero deberías usar `componentWillMount`. Estos metodos son invocados en un orden especifico, conocido como ciclo de vida o Life Cycle.

Los eventos se producen en el siguiente orden:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver, `componentDidMount` se ejecuta luego de `render` y por lo tanto el estado que estableces ahí, aun no esta definido en el momento que render es invocado.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo que he refactorizado un poco para que funcione en los StackSnippet, pero es equivalente a tu ejemplo anterior.

Salu2

```js
var data = {
  "datos": {
    "titulo": "Esto es el título",
    "actualizacion": "22/10/2016 19:10:42",
    "estado": "Cerrado"
  }
}

var Resumen = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      results: []
    };
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.setState({
      results: data
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    const { datos } = this.state.results
    return (
      <div>
            <br/>
            <p>Título: {datos.titulo}</p> 
            <p>Actualización: {datos.actualizacion}</p>
            <p>Estado: {datos.estado}</p>
          </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Resumen/>, document.querySelector('.main'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"></div>
```